# PhantomJS sets permissions of files to 644, how to change them without going anti-pattern?

Tags: api, permissions, phantomjs

I have implemented a restful API where i receive a website and return path to screenshots
I am using PhantomJS v 2.0.0 development to make the screenshots. I am making a console command that is executed with a secured, system()-like function. I use SU to log as a user 'phantomjs', which is restricted to use only specified commands, and then call my phantomjs script to render webpages as jpegs. The files outputted are owned by 'phantomjs' and have permissions set to 644. We have added the user 'phantomjs' to group www-data.

We are putting lots of webshots in a directory, and separate them alphabetically in sub-directories.So far so good. Our work scenario requires that we occasionally delete webshots.
So i implemented a restful delete-api which clients can use to delete their webshots. The real problem emerges from the fact that the files are owned by 'phantomjs' and with permissions set to 644, we can't delete the files through www-data. Since 'phantomjs' is in the same group with www-data, we need the permissions to be set to 664 in order to be able to unlink() those.

We wouldn't like to allow the user 'phantomjs' to use chmod or rm, because this would go against our design idea to restrict the user maximally, since this user runs shell commands.
We don't like the solution to run a cronjob that changes file permissions, because the server is pretty busy, and this solution is very undesirable and should be our last resort/
We tried using ACL making every file in webshots/ dir to have default permissions of 664, but this didn't work with our NFS as expected. Upgrading the NFS is not an option for me right now.
We tried umask 002, but this worked only with files created through the shell, so it couldn't help us either.

I've noticed that if i save an empty file through sublime-text , file permissions are 664.
If i save a screenshot with phantomjs, f.p. are 644. 
My questions are:
-What governs default file permissions, the running process itself or some user preferences from which you run the application?
-Can you give me any more ideas how to delete webshots securely or make 'phantomjs' owned files have perms 664 without giving the user too much 'dangerous' permissions.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you.